# VS Code Markdown Bold Shortcut Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Usually,  <kbd>cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>b</kbd>  or  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>b</kbd>  (in Windows) will make the selected text bold in a Markdown file but that's not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: see also the [`yzhang.markdown-all-in-one`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) extension (I have no affiliation with this extension). also related: [Prevent ctrl-B from setting bold font while working with md files with the Markdown All in One extension](/q/75305947/11107541).

Answer (score 4):

By default,  <kbd>cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>b</kbd>  is the keyboard shortcut for toggling sidebar visibility. To change it, add the following block of code in the keybindings.json file:

```
    {
        "key": "cmd+b",
        "scope": "markdown",
        "command":"editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when":"editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'markdown'",
        "args":{
            "snippet":"**$TM_SELECTED_TEXT**$0"
        }
    }
```